Trying to pull cell value from another sheet while making drag fill to skip every 7rows in formula
I am trying to create a spread sheet in Google Sheets that has one sheet as a daily update with a 7day avg while the other sheet pulls the weekly average from the daily sheet and then calculates the difference. I have difference and pulling value from the other tab figured out. Trying to save time by dragging the reference formula down but I can't get it to skip to every eighth cell value
ex. ='Progress Sheet (Athlete Only)'!A9  -- (simple) but I need "!A9" to jump to "!A17" and so forth when dragging the formula down.
I tried =offset and =index but I am struggling to figure it out.
Tried =index and =offset but not too familiar with the function when referencing another sheet

Use SEQUENCE() function generate numbers skipping 8 rows. Give a try to the following formula-
=MAP(SEQUENCE(50,1,9,8),LAMBDA(x,INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,x)))

Replace Sheet2 by your sheet name.


Is the 50 in the first spot as an end number? So the Sequence will end at 50? Also the x’s are they just for a variable? I appreciate the answer I just want to make sure I understand so I can do more troubleshooting in the future.

@Aaron You are correct. You need to adjust 50 as per need. We can also make it dynamic as per data in sheet2!A:A column.

Thank you again!

I got it to work. I was having a REF error because I was typing in the Sheet Name instead of 'Sheet Name'
